# Notepad++ Put double quotes when finding a character

Tags: notepad++

given: csv file with 500 lines of information What kind of search and replace can be done in notepad++ through regular expressions or through extended ones, so that when a certain character is found in a line (System characters ", ', >, <, &) it puts double quotes at the beginning and at the end of the line? And not to duplicate them if they are already standing. Example:

```
Before:

0104603702762113215qj6cNs4rKxfQ
0104603702762113215FG6z)r(l,\>1a
0104603702762113215y6J/X4L&sN-B
0104603702762113215oDkQqvP:/UXE
0104603702762113215LBT-fDGdwt9K
0104603702762113215Bb-XVT2Nzn;Y
0104603702762113215JBUVwSR%LiUk
0104603702762113215+8TMGXu;pFv"
0104603702762113215kIZw=!("ftkM
0104603702762113215ZBFp6R,oE"C\>
0104603702762113215dn%.YsAQMKNa
0104603702762113215\>tklJqLXn(jb

After:

0104603702762113215qj6cNs4rKxfQ
"0104603702762113215FG6z)r(l,\>1a"
"0104603702762113215y6J/X4L&sN-B"
0104603702762113215oDkQqvP:/UXE
0104603702762113215LBT-fDGdwt9K
0104603702762113215BbXVT2Nzn;Y
0104603702762113215JBUVwSR%LiUk
"0104603702762113215+8TMGXu;pFv""
"0104603702762113215kIZw("ftkM"
"0104603702762113215ZBFp6R,oE"C\>"
0104603702762113215dn%.YsAQMKNa
"0104603702762113215\>tklJqLXn(jb"
```

I tried to write a regular expression myself, but it turns out garbage.
I also tried to find something similar on the Internet and so far my maximum - I found how to put double quotes at the beginning and end of EACH line through \r\n - "\r\n"
And how to put commas at the end of each line alt + C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*["'><&].*$`
- Replace with: `"$0",`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    .*          # 0 or more any character
    ["'><&]     # 1 of these characters
    .*          # 0 or more any character
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
"           # double quote
$0          # the whole match (i.e. the entire line
"           # double quote
,           # a comma
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]